# How to install a patch for numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, patch, pyinstaller, bayesian-networks

I am trying to install OpenBayes, but I get an error, that the numarray is not found.

```
>>> from OpenBayes import BNet
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenBayes\__init__.py", line 7, in 
<module>
 from bayesnet import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenBayes\bayesnet.py", line 23, in 
<module>
import numarray as na
ImportError: No module named numarray
>>>
```

As I got it, the numarray is now replaced by numpy.
There is a patch for Numpy here: https://github.com/willasaywhat/OpenBayes-Fork
But don't know how to install it.

I use Python 2.7 and have Win10/

Thanks for any info about this module!

Comment: I would be scared to use abandoned software like that (no progress for 6 years) and would look for alternatives. Besides that, here is my interpretation: there is no patching-process, you just import the code into your code (and make sure the requirements are fulfilled like explained in the readme). So just copy these sources to your code and do the correct import. The repository does not seem to give you some global-install script (no real install possible).

Comment: Thanx a lot, I'll try it)